# eclipse automatic build does start only after a while for test-package

Tags: eclipse

How can I tell eclipse to increase the time to look for changed files so that eclipse re-builds them automatically. Currenty, in most cases, I have to wait approx. 10-50 seconds after eclipse will start a rebuild of my test-package.
In the meantime I have to wait for an indefinite time of a few tens of seconds to get the newest compiled version - and this is annoying.

Maybe it has to do something with my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.11
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Xms4g
-Xmx9g
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-javaagent:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

I use Eclipse Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0) on Mac OS.

My .project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>my-project</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.jboss.tools.jst.web.kb.kbbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.jboss.tools.cdi.core.cdibuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.metamodelBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
        <nature>org.jboss.tools.jst.web.kb.kbnature</nature>
        <nature>org.jboss.tools.cdi.core.cdinature</nature>
        <nature>org.jboss.tools.ws.jaxrs.nature</nature>
        <nature>org.jboss.tools.jsf.jsfnature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: In the preferences _General > Workspace_ the option _Refresh using native hooks or polling_ is enabled and the workspace is on a local drive, right?

Comment: @howlger yes, hooks are enabled and its on a local right. Is `-XX:+UseG1GC` or any other settings in `eclipse.ini` the reason?

Comment: I don't think so. In the _Project Explorer_ or _Package Explorer_, when you hit _Refresh_ (F5) you do not have to wait, right? If yes, please tell which file system do you have where the workspace is. If no, show your `.project` file (for which project builder are used) and tell whether you have some antivirus software that scans files when they are accessed.

Comment: Manual refresh works - don't have to wait. The FileSystem on Mac OS where the workspace is: APFS-Volume. I don't have any antivirus software in the background. I pasted my `.project` above in the question.

Comment: Looks like [Eclipse bug 570794](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=570794) (in contrast to Windows, for macOS native hooks are not yet implemented).